# Angular 4 - Post Checkbox Input as Array

Tags: angular

I have a working User Create form that I want to add some checkboxes as a feature. However, I couldn't have done it. I appreciate if anyone can show me the way.

**user-create.component.html:**

```
<form role="form">
    <input name="name" type="text" #userName>
    <input name="surname" type="text" class="form-control" #userSurname>
    <div class="form-group form-md-checkboxes" *ngIf="roles">
        <input name="roles[]" type="checkbox" *ngFor=let role of roles" value="{{role.id}}" #userRoles>
    </div>
    <button (click)="add(userName.value, userSurname.value, userRoles);" type="button">Create</button>
</form>
```

**users.component.ts:**

```
add(name: string, surname: roles: any): void {
    name = name.trim();
    surname = surname.trim();

    this.userService.create(name, surname, roles);
}
```

**user.service.ts:**

```
create(name: string, surname: string roles: any): Promise<User> {
    return this.http
        .post(this.usersUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name, surname: surname, roles: roles}), {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I can successfully fetch userName and userSurname values, but userRoles is always undefined.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S: I've tried userRoles.value in add function and #userRoles[role.id] in input definiton too.

Comment: It's not possible like that. You'd need to trigger a function when it's unclicked and clicked, and then add/remove the values in a array in the component... In a reactive form you could have a formarray, but there you also need to add/remove in component.

Comment: What I want to do is to get HTML value with name attribute, since when I give them a name "roles[]", it collects the result as an array. I just need its value.

Comment: Anyway, I had to do it as you suggested.

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you mean with your comment? Where does it collect to array? what do you mean with *its value* What is its value? Basically... What is your expected output?

Comment: When you post multiple inputs with name **roles[]**, the server gets it as an array of input values. I wanted to get a result similar to this, but had to write trigger functions instead. It is working, but I didn't like the method I used.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At the end, I ended up with running a function for value change.

**user-create.component.html:**

```
<form role="form">
    <input name="name" type="text" #userName>
    <input name="surname" type="text" class="form-control" #userSurname>
    <div class="form-group form-md-checkboxes" *ngIf="roles">
        <input name="roles[]" type="checkbox" *ngFor=let role of roles" value="{{role.id}}" (change)="onRoleSelectionChange($event, role.id)">
    </div>
    <button (click)="add(userName.value, userSurname.value);" type="button">Create</button>
</form>
```

**users.component.ts:**

```
selectedRoles: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedRoles = [];
}

onRoleSelectionChange(e, role: number): void {
    if(e.target.checked)
        this.selectedRoles.push(role);

    else{
        let index = this.selectedRoles.indexOf(role);

        if (index > -1) {
            this.selectedRoles.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}

add(name: string, surname: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    surname = surname.trim();

    this.userService.create(name, surname, this.selectedRoles);
}
```

**user.service.ts:**

```
create(name: string, surname: string, roles: any): Promise<User> {
    return this.http
        .post(this.usersUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name, surname: surname, roles: roles}), {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<form role="form">
    <input name="name" type="text" #userName>
    <input name="surname" type="text" class="form-control" #userSurname>
    <div class="form-group form-md-checkboxes" *ngIf="roles">
        <input name="roles[]" type="checkbox" *ngFor=let role of roles" value="{{role.id}}" id="userRoles">
    </div>
    <button (click)="add(userName.value, userSurname.value, userRoles);" type="button">Create</button>
</form>
```